# Is it possible to show readonly field value on hover in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I have private readonly string field in my C# class.
Is it possible to show field value on hover?

```
private readonly string _someValue = "123123123";
```

And when I use this in code I want to hover over usage and see its value in a tooltip (in a normal mode, not in debug).

Currently when I hover over variable in code Intellisense shows me something like 'string SomeClass._someValue'. I'd like to also see its value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean? Are you talking about when viewing the value in the debugger? If so, why & how doesn't that work already?

Comment: This makes no senses at all.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify its meaning. Hopefully I get it right.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a wild guess here which is probably wrong, but hey-ho! :)

If your goal is to make the debugger display certain information for one of your types when you hover over an instance of that type, you can use the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx).

For example, suppose you wanted your `readonly _someValue` string to be displayed on mouse hover while debugging, you can do this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("SomeValue = {_someValue}")]
public class Test
{
    private readonly string _someValue = "123123123";
}
```

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. It would be if you would use a `const` instead of `readonly`, but VS doesn't support this as of now (VS2013, R#8).

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149526/visual-studio-free-addin-or-resharper-plugin-to-show-constant-value-in-tooltip).