# How do you assign/edit a variable in a separate class, in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to assign a string to a variable in a separate class and then call on the variable later on in the code. How to write to variables in other classes and use them later on?

I have a public class called `Player` and a string variable called `playerName` declared as `public` and `static`. In my Program.cs I'm trying to assign the variable with `Player.playerName = Console.ReadLine();` but, when I call on it later it returns nothing.

Comment: [google c# what is a property](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+what+is+a+property). You will also want to know about classes and instances. Basically it sounds like you need an [OOP](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+oop) tutorial.

Comment: You will need an *instance* of the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to store a group of constants that my program uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724025/whats-the-best-way-to-store-a-group-of-constants-that-my-program-uses)

Comment: @CalHoff: wow, that's a lot of code (edit your question)

Comment: Basically I have a public class called "Player" and a string variable called "playerName" declared as public and static. In my Program.cs I'm trying to assign the variable with "Player.playerName = Console.ReadLine();" but, when i call on it later it returns nothing.

Comment: Could you also paste your code into your question, please. Just click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54444989/edit) button.

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer if you show us the code you are using.  Show a snippet of the `Player` class that shows the "string variable" (it is more likely a _field_ or a _property_ of the class).  And show us the "Program.cs" code where you set  and read it back.  You can also explain what you mean by "nothing".  `Nothing` is a keyword in Visual Basic (it's what C# calls `null`), but it has no meaning in C#.  Are you getting `null` or an empty string?

Comment: @CalHoff: Can you show the code you are using to both assign & read back the string.

Comment: Dare I ask why you've declared the string as `static`?

Comment: @PaulF - Andrew Morton commented before my edit and the OP's comment.

Comment: @CalHoff: if you do add the code - do it by editing your question rather than adding a comment. You need to start each line with 4 spaces for it to be highlighted as code & retain formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please provide code example or describe better your problem?

One generic solution can be:

```
class Example
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Then:

```
//instance of the class
Example example = new Example();
//set the property:
example.MyProperty = "value";
//access the property:
example.MyProperty
```

Comment: Me neither, but you could flesh out your answer a little, @meta4. Also, I would describe how to access the property from within the class and how to pass the class as an argument to a function or method.  The problem with the OP is that there's not enough detail; Calhoff is obviously completely new to OOP.

Comment: That's a start, @meta4, but just adding a couple more words to your comment lines isn't enough - keep going...

Comment: It should also be pointed out OP said the string was declared as static (after you posted this to be fair).

Comment: @PaulF but also he mentions it's 'playerName' for 'Player' which does not make much sense to be static.

Comment: Then you should explain why it doesn't make sense and what to do instead.

Comment: In all probability it should not be static, but if we saw the code then we could advise on that with more knowledge of the application. I would tend to try to answer the initial question as well as advise on improvements. As described, whether or not the field is static, the field should contain a value.