# c# Consts in a public class

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a class below:

I want to access these default strings but C# compiler doesn't like combining Const to create a Const.

```
public class cGlobals
{
    // Some Default Values

    public class Client
    {
        public const string DatabaseSDF = "database.sdf";
        public const string DatabaseDir = "database";
        public const string DatabaseFullLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                                                       DatabaseDir);
        public const string DataSource = Path.Combine(DatabaseDir, DatabaseSDF);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way instead of hard coding the strings? I want to make use of the Special Folders and Path.Combine.

Thanks

Comment: I would liek to thank everyone for their answers, static public readonly string has solved this problem.  I also use AppSettings so I really want to accept everyones answer here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use `static readonly` instead of `const`, since `const` have to be a constant at compile-time.

Also, constants will actually be compiled into assemblies that are using them, so if you are referencing those fields from other assemblies you would have to recompile them if you changed the constants. This doesn't happen with `static readonly` fields. So either way, it's a better idea :)

*I actually asked about this a while ago and I would recommend reading it and the accepted answer: [static readonly vs const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const).*

Answer (score 4):

For a variable to be declared `const`, the assigned value has to be a *compile-time* constant; to use the result of a method call you need to change your variable declaration:

```
public static readonly string DataSource = ...;
```

If you think about it, this *isn't* a compile-time constant, in that it will give different results based on which OS you run it on. It's constant *within a single execution* but not a "general" constant.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the other correct answers: a constant should logically be something that is *unchanging for all time and all places*.  Things like the number of eggs in a dozen, the atomic number of lead, and so on.  Values that change over time, like the number of countries in the European Union, or the price of a troy ounce of gold in Australian dollars, should not be modeled as constants.

In your case, the value is not logically constant for all time and all places, so don't try to use a constant.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `readonly` instead of `const`.

You could also look at using `app.config` to store your configuration settings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you will have to use

```
static public readonly string DatabaseFullLocation = Path.Combine(/* ... */);
```

instead;

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would not hard code the strings at all.

I'd put them into appSettings.

Why?  Well, if you need to change those values, you'll need to recompile your code.  Putting them in as appSettings will allow you to just change your config file.

You can still provide an accessor through your class.

```
public string DatabaseSDF 
{
  get
  {
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseSDF"];
  }
}
```

Best of both worlds, imo.

Comment: I do this already, but I am looking for specifying some default strings for the first time the app it run.  Using static public readonly string has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> **const types have to be identified at compile time, in your code you're
>   trying to call Path.Combine at
>   run-time to figure out the actual
>   path. And you cannot update const at
>   runtime.**

Answer (score 0):

In Application Settings  you can keep these kind of Constants .

In project properties ,select the settings tab. In the grid you can set your constants.

You can get as well as set these variables even during  runtime.

```
 Message.show(My.Settings.YourVariable); //you will get the value
```

and set by

```
 My.Settings.YourVariable="Vibin";
    My.Settings.Save()
```

I think this is one of the best way.

Comment: thanks, this is what I am doing.  I wanted to define the default values as consts hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a class lets say GetDirectory.
2. Make all methods static.
3. Define a class for constants.
   delcate all variables with --> public static readonly string Name_Of_Var = "Any value"
4. From GetDirectory methods - Define the code for folder you need to access
   Ex: Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder. "Select name of folder"), name of constants)

Done.