# Const field or get property

Tags: c#

What's the difference between the first and second definitions?

```
//1
private static string Mask
{
   get { return "some text"; }
}

//2 
private const string Mask  = "some text";
```

Which benefits has the first and the second approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Static readonly vs const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const)

Comment: @Danny, this is not about readonly fields, this is about properties returning a constant expression.

Comment: @Albin: It does however have similar semantics and is effectively the same thing.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: A property with `get` accessor only can be *considered* as readonly.

Comment: No, `readonly` means that the object can not be replaced once initializers and constuctors are done. A `get` property can return different objects every time called.

Comment: On the surface it sounds like a duplicate, but it is in fact not, but to be honest I would much rather have that duplicate edited to be *the one authority on the subject* rather than fragmenting this. However, a property that returns the same value every time is not the same as a readonly field or a const.

Comment: @Albin I think the point here was that the property does in fact *not* return different values every time it is called, but rather returns the same value every time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as they are private they will probably be optimized to more or less the same code. The re is another story if they are public and used from other assemblies.

`const` variables will be substitued/inlined in other assemblies using the `const` expression. That means that you need to recompile every assembly using the `const` expression if you change the expression. On the other hand the property solution will give you a method call overhead each time used.

Comment: Here is a good detailed explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10362203/2254197

Answer (score 4):

Basically `const` fields value evaluated at compile time and initiailized at declaration only.
Also important point that they are stored in the `assembly metadata` so there is could be a problem when you distributing assembly across the customers and then give them an updated version, so they need to recompile assemblies which referencing const to pick up an updated value as well.

In few words `static` field is something like a global variable which is accessible without instantiating any instance of underlying type, but in your case `private` access modifieds makes it unaccessible out of the type where it declared.

**EDIT:**

Very good Community Wiki post regarding constants: [Referencing constants across assemblies](http://justpaste.it/referencing_constants_across_ass) (post no longer exists as of June 2013.)

Answer (score 0):

`const` is a keyword of the language. 1s defined, your not allowed to change it down the line. Yes the property also depicts the same story, but it can have much more structure in it.

Answer (score 0):

In `const`, Once initialize can not modify. `get` can also not modify.
But when you have a scenario where you need different values every time you call Or, your value depends on any other function call, `get` will be used.

```
private static string Mask
   {
       get
       {
           var someOtherMethodText = SomeOtherMethodText();
           return "some text" + someOtherMethodText;
       }
   }
```