# Is it possible to have a getter for a const?

Tags: c#, properties

Just curious, is there a way to have a getter for a constant variable? I have a sort of internal version number to ensure that two versions of a library are still speaking the same language, but I'd like the programmer to be able to check what version they're using. Right now I use:

```
 private const Int16 protocol_version = 1;
 public Int16 ProtocolVersion => protocol_version;
```

But I'd prefer to do it with just the const if there's a way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what you use right now, because your code won't compile. Also, something like a protocol version is not suitable for a `const` field, because it's not actually constant – it may change in the future.

Comment: @svick Ah yes, my code doesn't actually have a set in it, I should change that in the answer. This was just my first thought before I tried to compile it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could declare a property with only a get accessor (without even declaring the set accessor, not even private):

```
private const Int16 protocol_version = 1;
public Int16 ProtocolVersion => protocol_version;
```

This is not the same as defining a constant only: the constant would be resolved at compile time, so if you update the library without recompiling the dependent program, the program would still see the "old" value. Consider this example:

```
// The class library
using System;

namespace MyClassLibrary {
    public class X {
        public const Int16 protocol_version = 1;
        public Int16 ProtocolVersion => protocol_version;
    }
}

// The program
using System;
using MyClassLibrary;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var x = new X();
        Console.WriteLine($"Constant: {X.protocol_version0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Getter: {x.ProtocolVersion}");
    }
}
```

Now, compile the first time and execute the program. You will see

```
Constant : 1
Getter : 1
```

Then, modify protocol_version to 2, and recompile *the class library only, without recompiling the program*, then put the new class library in the program folder and execute it. You will see:

```
Constant : 1
Getter : 2
```

The fact is that if it's just a constant, the value is replaced *at compile time*.

I think that what you are actually looking for is a `static readonly` variable: in that way, you will avoid the compile-time const replacement, and the variable will not be modifiable after initialization:

```
public static readonly Int16 protocol_version = 1;
```

Comment: That's a goo point, but if something is not a constant, then don't make it a `const` field in the first place.

Comment: @svick: seeing how the question was formulated ("I'd prefer to do it with just the const") I thought that maybe the distinction was not clear for him.

Comment: This is a good point, I wasn't aware that constants worked like that

Comment: But wouldn't that mean the getter is a good idea here? It avoids the problem of the program thinking it's using an older protocol if the library is actually updated. Though, as svick pointed out, I could just as easily use a non constant variable. I really only used const as a reminder to myself that it should never programatically change

Comment: @cost: then you could use a `static readonly` variable instead of a `const`. With that, you will avoid the problems of constness, and the variable will not be modifiable once initialized.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking readonly was just the VB equivalent of const. I'm curious though, what is the functional difference between using the constant with a getter (which still returns the correct value even with only recompiling the library) and the readonly? I'm going to change it to readonly, but I'm just wondering

Comment: @cost: look at the example again, and try to think about the const variable as a text replacement at compile time... on the other side, the `static` variable is always resolved at run time, and readonly only enforces that it cannot be modified after initialization. Hope this is clear...

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind the reason for the existance of getters/setters. It is to control access to an encapsulated variable, specifically to control how a variable is changed and who can change it. Since a const is set only once and remains read-only on runtime there is no reason to create a property for it. Setting the constant to public is completely acceptable since it is not a private variable that needs to be protected.

If you really... really want to make it a property then just define it as a readonly property, skip the setter entirely:

```
public Int16 ProtocolVersion => protocol_version;
```

But just so we are clear, I would say normally you would have public constants with the same coding style as properties:

```
public const Int16 ProtocolVersion = 1
```

Comment: I know it's kind of stupid, I was just trying to be consistent with my library

Comment: @cost I actually get that :) Just make public properties and constants have the same coding style and the intellisense will show it in a similar way. In some cases it's actually useful to be able to distinguish constants for properties because you know a constant can´t change but a readonly property tells you nothing about how the underlying variable is treated inside the class.

Comment: One additional point: there is no benefit in using `Int16` . Use `int`, `Int32` or maybe `string`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I use Int16 because the only use of the version number is to be sent across a socket as part of a handshake. I saw no need to send 4 bytes when 2 would be far more than enough

Comment: @cost: If you need to send a million versions then that is a valid point.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Just doing my part to keep the internet free for watching Netflix and that sort of thing

Comment: @cost: TCP doesn't send bytes, it sends packets. Your version will be in a bus with a lot of empty seats.

Comment: @HenkHolterman And the version isn't the only thing sent in the handshake. Regardless, TCP packets are not fixed size. Using a 32 bit int would still result in a packet two bytes larger. And besides, what harm is a 16 bit int besides suffering from not being aligned in memory

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
public const Int16 protocol_version = 1;
```

This will provide a public getter as a `const` cannot have a setter.

Comment: This might sound silly, but when I use get and set for the variables I get a different icon in intellisense than when I have a publicly exposed variable. All of my other exposed variables use getters and setters (some private) and I wanted to be consistent since it's a library

Comment: This is not the same as a property with a getter: if you update the library, you would also have to recompile the program.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco Why would you need to recompile the program? The only reason the programmer can view the version number is because the library, which uses this as part of a socket wrapper, will refuse to talk to another instance of the library where the protocol might be old/new. Instead of just saying "they don't match, too bad" I wanted the programmer to be able to get the version, even if they can't really do anything with it. I was trying to not be enigmatic.

Answer (score 0):

Constants cannot be reassigned, hence why they are called constant therefore just make protocol_version `public`

```
private const Int16 protocol_version = 1;
```

Comment: And then call it `ProtocolVersion`