# How to includ my 2d maps for my windows phone game?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, 2d

Im making a silly 2D game but is struggling a bit with external files that describes how the map should look like.

I currently have map001.txt that looks like this

```
00000000000000000000
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111110
01111111111111111110
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

Using TextReader does not make it happen, it cant seem to find the file :(

Comment: What are the map001.txt files settings in your project? Is it a resource or content? And you could share some code to how you tried to access the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 uses [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which is different approach than other systems e.g. Windows 7.

I assume you are using C# and you have maps predefined. You have two options

- Include file in the project
- write this map string into the code

there are more option - like using database - but these two are simple and good enough. If I were you I would go with second one. Map looks pretty simple, so the loading time and memory using shouldn't be a problem.

Best way is to define a helper (if you are interested why I made it [static readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const) here's an explanation)

```
public static class MapHelper
{
    public static readonly string Map = @"
                                          00000000000000000000
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          01111111111111111110
                                          00000000000000000000
                                          00000000000000000000
                                          00000000000000000000
                                          ";

}
```

Now if you want to extract the map as lines here a snippet

```
  var lines = Map.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to get the width and height use

```
        width = lines.Select(x => x.Length).Max();
        height = lines.Length;
```

Comment: Since i have very small maps, this would work i think. For larger projects i would like to make a seperate editor and store data in exernal files. thanks