# Which is preferable: "const" or "static readonly"?

Tags: c#, static, resharper, constants, readonly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Static readonly vs const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const)

Which is preferable in this instance (no pun intended): "const" or "static readonly"?

I changed some const declarations to static readonly after either reading that was better or being adivsed somewhere (quite possibly here on StackOverflow).

Now ReSharper wants to change:

```
private static readonly int NUMBER_OF_QUARTER_HOURS = 96;
```

to:

```
private const int NUMBER_OF_QUARTER_HOURS = 96;
```

Should I submit or "draw iron"?

Comment: This question is asked every second day on SO.

Comment: Have you noticed that the naming conventions for .NET are **NumberOfQuarterHours** for static and const fields? (PascalCase and not ALL_CAPS.)

Comment: @Danny - Yes, I have seen that before, but I don't like it, as it's then not clear (to me, anyway) that it's a const.

Comment: How does the consumer of a constant care whether it is constant or not?

Comment: @ClayShannon Does it really matter if it is a const!? What matters is that the values is correct (unless you are trying to pass it as a parameter to an attribute). Anyway, the IDE gives great indications in the auto complete dialog and on mouse over. Uniform standards gives a great advantage and .NET has a pretty good standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const if you know the value before compile time.

Comment: That is not necessarily true; the link @Tim posted shows an example where a compile-time value should be `static readonly`.