# ASP.MVC application constants, what is the best/most elegant approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, constants

Simple question really,

I am just looking for community support what works best architecturally.

Say, following case: `TempData["MySetting"]`? Where should I store `"MySetting"`? Should it be

1. in separate class so that the access will be `TempData[Config.MySetting];`
2. in web.config so that the access is `TempData[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];`
3. inline, leave it as string `TempData["MySetting"];`?
4. in the DB in some constants table, so that

   ```
   var mySetting = (string)_db.GetConstant("MySetting");
   TempData[mySetting];
   ```

I would not deal with option 4, just brought it for completeness of the picture.
So what do you suggest **and why**?

**Edit**
Question is rather general about constants in asp mvc rather than TempData case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your settings change? Depending on environment you deploy? If yes, then you definitely want to store them in the Web.config file (you could even make a custom section if it's not as simple as a couple of key/value pairs).

If they're the same on all the environments you use (including your own development box, the server and any testing/staging machines you might want to deploy) then I would go for the first option: declare a class with a few constants.

As far as storing them in the database goes, it really depends what kind of settings. If you want them to be per-user of your website, then you might end up storing them in your database. Or in case you want to be able to change them (editing the web.config file while the website is running is not the best idea).

I'd try staying away from leaving it as it is, inline.

Comment: What you mentioned makes sense. Any other options besides 1-4? How to create custom section (no idea) - can please update the answer? Thanks for taking time

Comment: You can check this URL for a good description on how to create a custom section for your Web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

As far as other options, it really depends on what exactly you are trying to store, and your specific application.

Answer (score 4):

In your particular case you should make a wrapper around `TempData` which will expose your data as property. All the access to `TempData` should be hidden inside that wrapper. In this case all the usages of `"MySetting"` will be limited to *at most* two. If there's only one usage, you don't need to do anything. If there're two - you define your `"MySetting"` as `private const` field.

In short:

```
public static class TempDataWrapper
{
    private const string _mySettingName = "MySetting";

    public int MySetting
    {
        get { return (int) TempData[_mySettingName];}
        set { TempData[_mySettingName] = value;}
    }
}
```

For the sake of brevity we are not dealing here with coupling (which is tight) and error-handling (which is none).

Comment: Thanks. My question was rather general than specific. How to deal with different constants inside the MVC app?

Comment: The same way as in any other app. They are *constants* - they should be hard-coded. All the other things depend on usage, and *on usage only*. There's no such thing as general approach in this matter.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static readonly string MyValue = "SomeValue";
}
```

More about [Const vs Readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach:

```
public static class Constants
{
       public static class Actions
       {
            public const string Administration = "Administration";
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that your constants are *really* constants, they will not change at runtime. For this scenario you use the `const` field modifier and in some cases `static readonly` modifiers to set up your constants values.

```
public class MyConstants {
    public const string MyConstantNameValue = "Value";
    public const int MyConstantNameValue2 = 123;

    // prevent the class to be instantiated
    protected MyConstants() { }
}
```

As you see you don't define the `MyConstants` as a static class because you can extend the constants if you need another set of constants for a specific namespace for example (plus the global constants).

```
public class MyConstantsPlusSpecificNamespaceConstants : MyConstants {
    public const string MySpecificConstantName = "Value2";
}
```

Comment: By the same token you can define is as partial and extend without sub classing. Thanks.

Comment: If the partials are in the same assembly, yes you can.