# Why would this compile?

Tags: c#, constants

I created a "const" for a value previously explicitly stated several times in my code:

```
private static readonly int QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT = 96;
```

When I did a search-and-replace of 96 for QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT, I inadvertently also replaced the declaration, so it became:

```
private static readonly int QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT = QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT;
```

...yet it compiled. I would think that it would disallow that. Why was it accepted by the compiler as a valid declaration?

Comment: Wow! That is sure surprising behavior.

Comment: I don't see a const. I see a readonly.

Comment: I think that's why he used quotes.

Comment: obligatory link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const

Comment: because there are an infinite number of ways to do it wrong.

Comment: Just confirming the equivalent VB.NET code also compiles with no error or warning and returns `0` of course.

Nor does VS2008 Code Analysis find this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I would think that it would disallow that. Why was it accepted by the compiler as a valid declaration?

Presumably because the language specification allows it. Do you have a specific rule in the language specification which you think prohibits it?

If your question is really "why doesn't the language specification prohibit this" - I suspect it's because it's probably quite hard to make sure you *only* prohibit things you really want to prohibit, while actually prohibit all such things.

You could argue that for *simple* cases of assignment directly back to itself, it would be good to have a special case in the language spec, but it would introduce complexity into the language for *relatively* little benefit.

Note that even if you didn't get an *error*, I'd expect you to get a warning - something like this:

> Test.cs(3,33): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

Also note that if you make it a `const` instead of just a static readonly variable, then you *do* get a compile-time error:

> Test.cs(3,23): error CS0110: The evaluation of the constant value for 'Program.QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT' involves a circular definition

Also note that by .NET naming conventions, this ought to be called `QuarterHourCount`, rather than having a SHOUTY_NAME.

Comment: Usage of unassigned variable I would have thought.

Comment: @leppie: Not for static fields in a static field initializer. The term "Unassigned variable" is irrelevant for static fields, which have no concept of definite assignment.

Comment: Actually there is, they are initialized in the order they are defined. This IMO breaks that rule.

Comment: @leppie They are all initialized after they are all defined (in the order that they were initially defined).

Comment: @leppie: There's an initialization order, but no concept of "unassigned variable" which is different. If you believe it actually violates a rule, can you point out the exact section of the spec you believe it violates?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Interesting ;p We have a hidden Y combinator! eg `static Func<int, int> f = x => (x == 0) ? x : f(x-1);`

Comment: @leppie: That would always capture `f` *at the point of execution* anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet: But the syntax would not be allowed otherwise ;p

Comment: @leppie: Well, it depends on what the rule was. That wouldn't work for local variables of course, but I could imagine a rule which would prohibit the OP's code but not your Y-combinator.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I did get that warning msg, but I didn't see it, as (at least in the way I've got VS set up) it doesn't display unless I explicitly look for it via View | Error List. As to the "shouty" name, I realize this is a controversial topic, and I certainly respect your opinion, but that is one of the stylistic trends I buck, because I find the "shouty" nomenclature easier to grok as I scan through the code; IOW, shouty == constants or "pseudo-constants" (readonly static)

Comment: @ClayShannon: This is a good reason to treat warnings as errors :) It's pretty easy to go warning-free in C#. As far as the conventions go - within "private" code that's okay, but I'd strongly advise you to follow conventions if you make the code public (e.g. an open source project).

Answer (score 6):

The IL code generated by the code is this:

```
 IL_0007:  ldsfld     int32 Example.Quat::QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT//Load the value of a static field on the stack
 IL_000c:  stsfld     int32 Example.Quat::QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT// Store the value from the stack in the static field
```

Since the default value of QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT is 0,the 0 is assigned to QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT

Answer (score 5):

Because the variable was initialized as 0 and then set to itself.

My guess would be that it would be doing a new Int() prior to setting to itself which would initialize it to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Because the compiler will break this line down:

```
private static readonly int QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT = QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT;
```

Basically into the IL equivalent of:

```
private static readonly int QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT;
QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT = QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT;
```

And then obviously that'll get broken down more too, but the above should suffice to illustrate my point.

So technically it'll exist with a default value of zero at the time it gets used.

Answer (score 0):

As others have implied value types like `int` have a default value so declaring a variable without explicitly initializing it means it still has a value.

You can find out the default value for any type like so:

```
int i = default(int);
```

Or more generally:

```
T t = default(T);
```

Note that for reference types the default will be `null`, only value types will have default values.