# Incosistent behaviour of List<long> property

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<long> myList = new List<long>() { 1,2,3 }
}
```

In another method:

```
var testList = Foo.myList;
```

If I put a breakpoint at the last line and inspect `testList` it gives me different lengths from time to time.

When I use `ToList()` on `Foo.myList` it seems to behave correctly. But why?

**Edit:**

My problem was that I made an ajax call > modified `Foo.myList` > new ajax call > fetched `Foo.myList` again and got the modified value.

Comment: Because you did modify it in another method? Check all Add/Remove calls to it and where you pass the reference around. Were items added or removed from it? That could help to narrow down the issue. To be on the safe side you can make it a propery which does return a copy of the list so you can be sure that nobody does modify it by accident.

Comment: If you are not sure you can derive from List and override the Add and Remove methods to throw execeptions. Then replace your List with your ReadOnlyList. This will give you direct insights where there modification is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Race condition on shared state. The static field member means there's **one** copy, so if you manipulate the list in your code, it changes for **ALL** threads using the property. `ToList()` works because it creates a **copy** of the list which won't alter the original list, but note that this copy **also points to the same objects as the original list if the objects are reference types**. Therefore altering the reference types in the copy would also alter the values in the original list... but since `long` is a value type that won't apply here.

If you want your list to be read-only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx

Comment: Ok, I was pretty sure that I didn't modify it. But I'll investigate the code again with this in mind. Thank you

Comment: If it's changing, you modified it. :D

Comment: I right clicked `Foo.myList` > "find usages". Result: "this is the only usage"...

Comment: Ok, so I found the problem. Even though I make 2 separate ajax calls, the state of `Foo.myList` seems to be saved. I had no idea about this :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're modifying Foo.myList or a reference to it somewhere. Note that assigning the list to a local variable does not make a copy. Thus:

```
var list = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 };
var testList = list;
testList.Add(4); // list is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.Add(5); // testList is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

ToList(), on the other hand, makes a copy. In general, it's probably safest to make any static lists read only (if that's the semantics you want) to prevent this from happening accidentally:

```
public class Foo {
    // pre .NET 4.5, use ReadOnlyCollection<T> (which implements IList<T>)
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<long> myList = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 }.AsReadOnly();
}

var testList = Foo.myList.ToList(); // get an editable copy
var testList2 = Foo.myList; // get a reference to the immutable static list
```

Comment: Thank you, what would be the difference between `readonly` and `const` here?

Comment: @Johan in C#, const can only be used with compile-time constants like integers and strings. Readonly just prevents assignment outside of the constructor/static initializer. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I updated my question if you're intrested in the problem source.