# Singleton with exposed properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, singleton

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Constants
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Constants> lazy =
        new Lazy<Constants>(() => new Constants());

    public static Constants Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> validApplicationTypes;
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ValidApplicationTypes
    {
        get { return validApplicationTypes; }

    }
    private Constants()
    {
       // validApplicationTypes is populated from a DB table
    }
}
```

Now outside I access the valid application types like this:

```
Constants.Instance.ValidApplicationTypes
```

What would be the best way to add a bunch of string constants to this class? should I add them like:

```
private static readonly string message= "SomeMessage";
public static string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
        }
```

and access them like: `Constants.Message`

or should I add them like this:

```
   private string message= "SomeMessage";
    public string Message
            {
                get { return message; }
            }
```

and access them like: `Constants.Instance.Message`

Is there any difference between these 2 ways of creating them inside the singleton and accessing them from the outside?

Comment: Just because it's `static` doesn't make it a constant. Can they either be `const` or `static readonly`?

Comment: You are right, I missed the readonly. Fixed now

Comment: Use `const` or `static readonly` i see no reason in make them instance members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference between these 2 ways of creating them inside
>   the singleton and accessing them from the outside?

Yes.

The former implementation will created before any instance of `Constants` and will be accessible like this:

```
Constants.Message
```

The latter will not be created until `Instance` is initialized and will be accessible like this:

```
Constants.Instance.Message
```

---

Adding `readonly` to the field will not affect how it is accessed from "outside", but it will from the inside.  It will only be able to set during initialization or in the constructor of the class in belongs to.

```
private static readonly string message= "SomeMessage";
```

or

```
private Constants()
{
   message = "SomeMessage";
}
```

This will not compile if `readonly` is applied:

```
private void SetMessage()
{
    message = "SomeMessage";
}
```

Error:

> A static readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a static
>   constructor or a variable initializer)

Comment: thanks, got that now. Is there any advantage in using one way over the other of accessing the constant strings?

Comment: It would be my personal preference to make it non-static because I would expect to see Message as part of the instance and not a static part of the class.  Otherwise I can't think of one.

Comment: The first method allows you to access the constants without having to instantiate the class.  This is because the second way they are not constants as such, just normal fields/properties on a class that happen to be always set by the same string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why not

```
public const string Message = "SomeMessage";
```

?

Comment: For 2 reasons: I'm come from a Java background and `public static readonly` seemed very similar to `public static final`. And the second one is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @briandfoy, the question is "What would be the best way to add a bunch of string constants to this class?", and my answer provides a way that is the best (in my opinion, of course).