# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property

Tags: c#, .net

```
public readonly int items = 3;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[,] statsBonus = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[6, items];
```

It's giving me this error on the "items" variable. How do I make it so that I can use a variable called "items" instead of having to write 3 in every field that uses the number 3?

If I want to edit this on the code, I don't want to have to change the number 3 to something else manually. I want to use a variable so all I have to do is just change the variable to change everything.

Comment: public readonly int items = 3; is working on my computer. What version of .Net do you use ?

Comment: Read the error message, add static.

Comment: @cubitouch How do I find which version I'm using .NET? I'm on Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @puretppc Right click project -> Properties -> Application tab

Comment: @puretppc I'm reproducing your example into a console application with .Net 4.0. See you project properties for more informations.

Comment: Interesting... Someone can tell why my console app' is running fine ?

Comment: My bad, I was using the wrong line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `readonly` use `const`

EDIT:

For a more discussed difference between the two, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const)

Comment: It's running properly. But what's the difference between those 2 types?

Comment: @puretppc, *readonly* field value can be set in *constructor* and also field initializer, but *const* file value can only be set via field initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You must use

```
const int items = 3;
```

Comment: Readonly variables can be only assigned via constructer

Answer (score 1):

**One option**

Move it to the constructor:

```
public ClassName()
{
  statsBonus = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[6, items];
}
```

**Better option**

Make `items` a `const`.