# How to create alias of System Constants class

Tags: c#, winforms

IDE: C# .net, winforms VS 2010

I have a class SystemConstants.cs

As shown below:

```
public class SystemConstants
{

    //String Constants
    public const string Hello = "Hello";
    public const string Youth = "Youth";
}
```

And have Form1.cs

Now in form1.cs

```
txtbox1.text = SystemConstants.Hello;
txtbox2.text = SystemConstants.Youth;
```

Now I want to know is there any why by which instead of writing

```
SystemConstants.Hello; //I want to avoid writing class name or I want to use alias for class name


 Like this SystemConstants alias sc;
  txtbox1.text = sc.Hello;
```

Comment: Since `SystemConstants` is not a `static` class, why not have a `private static SystemConstants sc = new SystemConstants;` in your `Form1` and then use that? By the way, be very *very* careful with public constants. If they're public you should probably prefer `public static readonly`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const

Comment: If `SystemConstants` is not in the namespace of `Form1` then you need to write namespace name before class name `using sc = YourNamespace.SystemConstants;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; you can use a [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). Add this to the top of your Form1.cs file:

```
using Sc = MyNamespace.SystemConstants;
```

Comment: But `SystemConstants` is a class. Are you sure `using` can do that?

Comment: @SonerGönül - yes, see [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf0df423.aspx) Example 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing class alias at the top:

```
using sc = SystemConstants;
```

If `SystemConstants` is not in the namespace of `Form1` then you need to write namespace name before class name:

```
using sc = YourNamespace.SystemConstants;
```