# Does java provides class alias feature?

Tags: java

I have seen a question related to c#

[How to create alias of System Constants class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954559/how-to-create-alias-of-system-constants-class)

Can you tell me does java provides similar feature

for eg.

```
System.out.println(sc.Hello); //see previous question
//here sc is the alias of class name SystemConstants sc
```

SystemConstants.java class

```
class SystemConstants
{
  public static final Hello = "Hello";
  public static final Youth = "Youth";
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: There is a `using` functionality in Java 7. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943574/2591612

Comment: You can use `SystemConstans sc = null;` and then use `sc.Hello`, but it's really, really ugly, and obfuscates the code. Why would you want that? You can also `import static SystemConstants.Hello` and simply use `Hello` in the code.

Comment: @staticx it is not the same. OP's asking how to give an alias to a class name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not built-in alias system for class names in Java. If you have specific needs, introspection might help you, but if the matter is one of usability and easy coding, then it is probably overkill.