# Why I dont have access to an public const c# in an other class

Tags: c#, constants

I tried to access in my Test.cs to strings in my other class TerminalStrings.cs but was not able.... how can I access to them ?

TerminalStrings.cs :

```
namespace RFID_App
{
    class TerminalStrings
    {
        public static readonly string identiError = "ERROR";
        public const string identiSuccess = "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

In Test.cs:

```
 namespace RFID_App
    {
          class Test
        {
            public Test()
            {
               string test;
               TerminalStrings stringlist = new TerminalStrings();
               test = stringlist.identiError; //this was not possible 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: set the access to public as in public class TerminalString

Comment: @N4TKD wouldn't solve the problem at hand; may or may not be the accessibility he wants for the class.

Comment: @N4TKD, that has nothing to do with the error. OP is using both classes in the same namespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` are implicitly static, you can't access them with instance member instead you need the class name to access.

```
test = TerminalStrings.identiError;
```

See: [Why can't I use static and const together? - By Jon Skeet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx)

Comment: Is there a difference when I use "static readonly" or "const string"

Comment: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/755685/781792) Using `const` means that code will hardcode it at compile-time. Only do this for things that can never, ever even theoretically change, like `PI`.

Comment: I wouldn't even use it for Pi due to the fact that it cannot be exactly represented with floating point numbers, so you'll find different values for Pi through-out different programs and you might want to change it later.  I'd only use it for values that will never change and the exact value can be stored.  'Seconds in a day', 'feet in a mile', etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `const`s are not member variables, they are on the class.

```
string test = TerminalStrings.identiError;
```

Answer (score 1):

Constants in C# are automatically `static`. They're not part of the data of an *instance*, but of the *class* itself - after all, `stringlist` and `stringlist2` don't have different copies.

So to access it, access `TerminalStrings.identiError`:

```
public Test()
{
   string test;
   test= TerminalStrings.identiError;
}
```