# What is best to use, class or struct for only static fields inside

Tags: c#

I have several static fields and need to know what is the best container for them: `class` or `struct`?

```
public class/struct MySharedFields
{
    public static readonly string Field1 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field1");
    public static readonly string Field2 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field2");
    public static readonly string Field3 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field3");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. Struct/Class changes behavior of instances only.

Comment: Would I have advantage in this case to use Singleton or when all fields are static is  not an advantage? Actually static class or Singleton?

Comment: Having static classes can really impede testing. Making this class a singleton and giving it an interface that can be mocked would be an advantage when testing.

Comment: Go for singleton, which is injectable

Comment: And one more thing I think is worth adding here:
With static fields the syntax is just MySharedFields.Field1, when with the Singleton this syntax is not applicable and you will have to take the instance every time and make call via it. So it is more overhead for the programmer as well.

Comment: A few extra key strokes isn't even a consideration compared to the benefits. And anyway, if you inject the instance, it's almost exactly the same: `mySharedFields.Field1` (possibly `this.mySharedFields.Field1`, depending on your code style). If you create a static instance field on the class (make sure it's of the interface type), it's just an extra de-reference: `MySharedFields.Instance.Field1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually static class is the way to go, but it really doesn't make a difference. The plus is you can add Methods in the future if required.

```
public static class MySharedFields
{
    public static readonly string Field1 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field1");
    public static readonly string Field2 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field2");
    public static readonly string Field3 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field3");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use a class or struct, first time CLR loads a `Type` class. All objects of a type have a reference to that type avaliable via `GetType` method. Objects themself contains only instance fields, all methods and static fields are in `Type`. Instance methods takes implicit extra argument `this`. When you call instance method, object passes himself to method, which actualy defined in `Type`. Difference between struct and classes only in where they keep their fields: heap for classes and stack for struct. So there is no real difference between static method of class and struct. But you can mark class as static to prevent creating instances of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a static class, as C# doesn't allow static structs:

```
public static class MySharedFields
{
    public static readonly Field1 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field1");
    public static readonly Field2 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field2");
    public static readonly Field3 = AppConfig.GetValue("Field3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a class and struct in C# is very small.

I would say, use a class, because then you can easily afterwards add methods to it when needed.

Probably structs might have some performance advantages, but if that is not an issue, a class is probably in most of such cases the best way to go.

You can in your case make the class static, unless you have multiple instances or later you want to have multiple instances.

Comment: One more question then. When the code calls value of any field will it execute AppConfig.GetValue every time or only the first time? (They are readonly fields)

Comment: @st_stefanov it is going to be executed only the first time

Comment: @nsgovec (previous remark was for the first comment; I removed the abstract class remark.

Comment: @nsgovec - is this because the field is read only, or because it is static?

Comment: @st_stefanov because it is static. Difference between readonly and const can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const