# how does [<Literal>] differ from other constants in F#

Tags: f#

I am a bit confused by the Literal keyword and why it is necessary in F#.

Reading the docs, it sounds to me that `[<Literal>]` is used to define a constant, however I am a bit confused how this constant differs from all other constants in F#..

> Values that are intended to be constants can be marked with the
>   Literal attribute. This attribute has the effect of causing a value to
>   be compiled as a constant.

When I think of a constant, I think of something which is immutable....

```
let x = "a" + "b" //this is a immutable value, its value is constant
[<Literal>]
let y = "a" + "b" //this is also a immutable value, but why is this a special constant?
```

Is it because the 'normal' F# values are evaluated lazily and the `[<Literal>]` is not evaluated lazily..? is that what they mean with 'compiled as constant'..? or is there something else to it?

Comment: I found this question because I was also confused by that paragraph in the language reference, for the same reason, ie. every 'let' bound value in F# is "constant" so what's special about a `Literal`? The word "constant" does not have a particular meaning in F# which might explain this para. The answers here explained it well, but I have raised a github "issue" on the paragraph. https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/32082.

Comment: Opened a [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/39895) to clarify the `[<Literal>]` attribute.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In your example, `x` is an immutable value that is assigned during runtime (but NOT evaluated lazily), whereas `y` is assigned during compiletime. As an example,

```
let myDLL = "foo.dll"

[<DllImport(myDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern void HelloWorld()
```

will not work, because DllImport is an attribute and needs to know the value of `myDLL` during compilation. However, this will work:

```
[<Literal>]
let myDLL = "foo.dll"

[<DllImport(myDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern void HelloWorld()
```

Comment: You might also want to note the importance for .NET interop.  Fields decorated `[<Literal>]` are compiled into IL as constants, which has certain implications for consumers of your code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/755693/385844, for example.

Comment: Please note that according to f# naming conventions, literals should be PascalCase. If you use them for pattern matching, this is more than just convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals

Answer (score 30):

If you come from C# background, you can think of `Literal` values as `const` fields, and non-literal ones as `readonly` fields. The same differences apply.

Answer (score 15):

I think a better example is what happens in a `match`.

This doesn't do what you expect:

```
let t = 3
match q with
|t -> printfn "this always happens"
|_ -> printfn "this never happens" //and produces a compiler warning
```

on the other hand:

```
[<Literal>]
let t = 3
match q with
|t -> printfn "q is 3"
|_ -> printfn "q isn't 3"
```

So here as the `Literal` is a compile time constant we can use it for pattern matching.

Comment: Unfortunately, this example is case sensitive. To work as described the literal identifier `t` must begin with a capital letter. Using a capital for the non-literal version produces an additional compiler warning, but functions identically.

Comment: The example actually works, and produces "q is 3", but that's because `t` without a `when` clause matches every value. It's not the same `t` assigned in `let t = 3`. If you replace `|t` with `z` you get the same runtime result, but with `|t` you also get a compiler warning `FS3190: Lowercase literal 't' is being shadowed by a new pattern with the same name. Only uppercase and module-prefixed literals can be used as named patterns.`

Comment: I strongly recommend the syntax `let [<Literal>] T = 3` in order to avoid _code drift_ - that is, the attribute and the code element to which it applies easily drifting away from each other due to later edits.

Answer (score 2):

The docs with that paragraph ([Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals)) briefly refer to "pattern matching", the `when` clause, and the use of PascalCase identifiers, but need an example for clarity. Unfortunately, the above example of pattern matching is incorrect (by using lowercase `t` for the literal).

```
[<Literal>]
let X = 3   // PascalCase by convention for a literal

match 3 with 
| X -> "Pattern Matched with X" // PascalCase REQUIRED for pattern matching with a constant.
| x when x = X -> "Matched with X, via 'when'" // lower case is always a local identifier
| _ -> "false"

// RESULT 'val it : string = "Pattern Matched with X"'
```