# Where to define constants and use them anywhere?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

In Java I would write something like

```
public interface ICar {    
    static String RED_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_red.png";
    static String BLUE_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_blue.png";
    static String GREEN_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_green.png";    
}
```

Because C# doesn't allow using fields in interface, where do I define this constants in C#, when I wish to use them more than once?

Comment: What about a simple `public static class` ? and use `const` for constants, *which are implicitly static as well*

Comment: One more thing to add, these looks like path to images. Depending on the application you can use [Local Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well

Comment: Thanks, that's reasonable!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a static class to contain your constants (which need to be `public` as by default fields without modifier are `private`):

```
public static class Car
{
    public const string RED_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_red.png";
    public const string BLUE_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_blue.png";
    public const string GREEN_CAR = "/res/vehicles/car_green.png"; 
}
```

After this you can use constants like `Car.RED_CAR`.

Comment: @StuartLC that's true :)

Comment: I won't use `_` in names and no BLOCK letters. Remember this is C# not C++ and also probably rename the class to `CarLocation` or something similar.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel agree with you, but that's up to OP, I've just written the code based on the code he provided :)

Comment: Public constants with a content like this (that is likely to change) isn't a very good idea because once they are changed - you need to rebuild all assemblies potentially using these. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const) of an extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If all your constants are files it's better to include them in your resources.

In your project properties there's a resource section, vs can create a Resources.resx if you need one.
In there you can add all sorts of files or strings (for translations mostly).

You can then access them through `Properties.Resources.RED_CAR`

I would not name them like that though. It's from the time when all variables where globals and naming conventions like that where needed to know what was stored in the variable. But when accessing your data like this it's always clear what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I will use constants for files. Thanks for information about Properties.Resources, I didn't know about that, and I will try it right now!