# Assign Conditional Value to class member of static class

Tags: c#, class, constants

Here is my class :

```
namespace My.Core
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string Layer_ver_const = "23";

        public const string apiHash_const = "111111";
    }
}
```

Now i want to set conditional value for **apiHash_const**.
Mean :

```
if(Layer_ver_const == "23")
{
  apiHash_const = "111111";
}
else if(Layer_ver_const == "50")
{
  apiHash_const = "222222";
}
else
{
  apiHash_const = "333333";
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: If `Layer_ver_const` is a constant then how would any of your other values ever be set?

Comment: I have many Hash_codes. I want to change version manually in calss and this class return desire Hash_code.

Comment: Sounds like you should simply change your 'derived' constants to `static readonly` and set them in the static constructor.

Comment: I think @CharlesMager is right. I'm pretty sure the `const` keyword means it is a compile time constant and cannot be set programatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't do that at runtime. But you can always change the constant keyword to `static` or `static readonly` and this code will work.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Layer_ver_const = "23";

    public static readonly string apiHash_const;

    static Constants()
    {
       if(Layer_ver_const == "23")
       {
         apiHash_const = "111111";
       }
       else if(Layer_ver_const == "50")
       {
         apiHash_const = "222222";
       }
       else
       {
         apiHash_const = "333333";
       }
    }
}
```

If you want to know the difference between `constant` and `static readonly` checkout this link:

[Static readonly vs const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend turning these to a readonly field, and set them inside the constructor

Constants are a different beast. Once a constant is declared in a project, every other project referencing it will retain the value of the constant until you rebuild the projects. Thus, changing a constant is not what you want to do.

Make these readonly , and inside the constructor set them.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have specified, you probably want a `readonly` field instead. You could even use a property. Nevertheless, it *is* possible to have the field `const`, by making the entire expression that calculates it a constant expression:

```
public const string Layer_ver_const = "23";
public const string apiHash_const = 
    Layer_ver_const == "23" ? "111111" :
    Layer_ver_const == "50" ? "222222" :
    "333333"
;
```

This is possible only because we can construct a simple expression to assign `apiHash_const`. In more complicated scenarios you'll have to settle for a `readonly` field.