# How to use 'readonly' as member keyword in C# 8.0?

Tags: c#, readonly, c#-8.0

I like to know the correct way to use the `readonly` keyword for members introduced with **C# 8.0** in difference to the 'const' keyword.

Comment: I think it was introduced C#8?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#readonly-members

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/readonly-instance-members?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that correct ways are precisely described by [official proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/readonly-instance-members).
But to make a general comment I will add, that this `readonly` keyword for `struct`, does not really make functional changes to your existing code (except compiler warnings when `readonly` marked method tries to change the `struct` state). This new syntax, is infact a kind of indicator for compiler that allows it better code optimization by not generating extra copies of the value types. It has nothing in common with `const` keyword, because `const` is only applicable for constants of the basic types (like `int` or `string`) (See https://exceptionnotfound.net/const-vs-static-vs-readonly-in-c-sharp-applications/ &
[Static readonly vs const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const) on the question.

Comment: structs are not immutable

Comment: you are right, my apologies, for some reason I mistaken it because I never made them mutable =)

Answer (score 1):

Readonly exists since the beginning of C#.

Const is used to declare a constant value that is interpreted by the compilator as a raw value that is not an instantiated variable. It can not be an instance, it is a immutable value.
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const

Readonly is used to declare an instance that can't be re-assigned. It is an instance variable that can't be changed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly

For example, you can write:

```
const string MyString = "A string";
const int MyInteger = 10;
```

But you can't write:

```
const Form Instance = new Form();
```

You must use:

```
readonly Form Instance = new Form();
```

Readonly members can be assigned in a constructor.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/readonly-instance-members

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information about the new usage of this keyword. So the OP question has nothing to do about the const keyword? I found this usage a little confusing, hence the question of OP. Another keyword should have been introduced for that usage, like "unmutate".

Comment: @OlivierRogier Be careful what you wish for, or they'll decide to use `const`, and you'll get articles about const correctness, C# style.

Comment: @Ray I did not understand what you are saying. What wish? What correctness? What C# style? They? Const may be used in some cases for optimization...

Comment: @OlivierRogier Don't worry, it's just a pun on some people not being able to understand the many ways of applying the similar `const` keyword in C++.

Comment: @Ray I am not good enough in English that is not my native language :)