# Azure functions HttpTrigger, not using HttpMethods class in attribute

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

Why do functions in AzureFunctions requires to use

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLeve.Anonymous, "get")]
```

Instead of

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLeve.Anonymous,  HttpMethods.Get)]
```

Of course I cannot use

```
HttpMethods.Get.ToString()
```

becase language does not allow to call functions in Attributes

and creating my own

```
public static class HttpMethodsStrings
{
     public const string Get = "get";
}
```

seems redundant since .NET already provides HttpMethods.

Comment: if you think that the response answers your question, please mark it as answer to help other community folks.

Comment: well, it is much likely creating constants, I hoped MS provided the constants somewhere, but seems not, so I was waiting to accept. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.X` constants instead of hard coded strings ("get", "post"). I have put together the piece of code and debugged it and it works fine.
The snippet of the same is shown below -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your second example to use the `nameof` operator

eg

```cs
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLeve.Anonymous,  HttpMethods.Get)]
```

becomes

```cs
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLeve.Anonymous,  nameof(HttpMethods.Get))]
```