# In a Xamarin application how should I set up constants?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I am doing right now:

```
public static class CONST
{
    public static bool CarTmr = false;
```

Is this another way to do this that is more commonly used?

Comment: `public static readonly bool ...` or `public const bool ...` More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the [Microsoft recomended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-constants)

```
static class Constants
{
    public const double Pi = 3.14159;
    public const int SpeedOfLight = 300000; // km per sec.
}

// Accessible like
double area = Constants.Pi * (radius * radius);
```

So in your case:

```
public static class CONST
{
    public const bool CarTmr = false;
}
```

Depending on the situation, you could also setup a class that reads from the configuration, if those constants relate to runtime and might be changed in the future.

There is no `Xamarin` specific, better way to achieve it.