# How to define a constant literal in F#

Tags: f#

In C#, I do this:

```
 public const double PAPER_SIZE_WIDTH = 8.5 * 96;
```

What is the best way to define this global constant in F#?

This fails:

```
  [<Literal>]
  let PaperSizeWidth = 8.5*96.0
```

*Error: This is not a valid constant expression*

TIA

Comment: Defining `public const` is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756010/10339675) for libraries. You can precalculate value  and write `let PaperSizeWidth  = 816` and leave comment how you got this number. It will compile into static get-only property, which will be inlined by JIT during runtime. It you apply `[<Literal>]` it will compile to `public const`, but as mentioned above - it's bad practice.

Comment: I have to disagree that this is bad practice. I also looked at the link, and what is described there is simply an example of a mistake that any sensible developer wouldn't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arithmetic is [not yet supported for numeric literals](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/539) in F#. Instead, you have to provide the final value explicitly:

```
[<Literal>]
let PaperSizeWidth = 816.0
```

However, every value is immutable by default in F#, so this might be good enough, depending on your needs:

```
let PaperSizeWidth = 8.5 * 96.0
```

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question, because the equivalent of using the const keyword in C# is indeed to use the [<Literal>] attribute in F#. We call a literal a literal, and not a constant, otherwise confusion arises.

Comment: Ok, I had forgotten that C# consts are evaluated at compile time. F# doesn’t support similar arithmetic in literals yet. See the link in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is more informative than I thought at first. But I'd like to suggest you also add the alternative of calculating the expression and write let [<Literal>] PaperSizeWidth = 816.

Comment: I agree. I’ll update/clarify it tomorrow.