# Super class of String and Integer in Java 8

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

I'm writing a simple Predicate function as follows:

```
public static Predicate<String> stringPredicate(String op, String compVal) {
    if (op.equals("=")){
        return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == 0;
    }
    else if (op.equals("<")){
        return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == -1;
    }
    else if (op.equals("<=")){
        return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == 0 || p.compareTo(compVal) == -1;
    }
    else if (op.equals(">")){
        return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == 1;
    }
    else if (op.equals(">=")){
        return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == 1 || p.compareTo(compVal) == 0;
    }
    return p -> -1 == 0; //return false 
}
```

I'd like this function to work for both Integers, Floats and Strings. So, rather than writing 2 identical predicate functions, one for Strings and one for Integer+Float, I'd like to write a single one as compareTo() method works for all 3 of them. I guess I can do it by replacing 
`Predicate<String>` with `Predicate<Super class of Integer/Float/String>`. I tried `Object` but that didn't work. So, what should I put instead of `<String>` to use the function in the way I want?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I've if-else,if there right? Am I missing someting ?

Comment: @SpiderRico `equals` vs. `==`.

Comment: Ah I see now, yes. But that won't change much in terms of the correctness, right ?

Comment: @SpiderRico yes it will: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @SpiderRico Depends on which "correctness" you're referring to.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah you're right. Was a bit sleepy when writing this last night I guess.

Comment: Anyhow, what about the question :) ?

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks. That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no common "superclass" of `Integer` and `String` other than `Object`, which is useless for you since it doesn't have `compareTo`.

But there is a common *interface* between the two — [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), which provides the `compareTo` method.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Predicate<T> predicate(String op, T compVal) {
    switch (op) {
        case "=": return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) == 0;
        case "<": return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) < 0;
        case "<=": return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) <= 0;
        case ">": return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) > 0;
        case ">=": return p -> p.compareTo(compVal) >= 0;
        default: return p -> false;
    }
}
```

(Starting from Java 7 you could [switch on strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string), so there is no point using an if/else chain here. But in your case [an enum for `op` may even be more suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575376/why-use-enums-instead-of-constants).)

Comment: Thank you. This looks exactly what I need.

Comment: Consider **currying** based on a `Map<String,BiFunction<T,T,Boolean>`. `functionMap.put(">", (a,b) -> x.compareTo(y) > 0)` etc. Then `return p -> functionMap.get(op).apply(p,compVal)`. Or an enum instead of the map.

Comment: @slim That's just moving the `switch` into a `Map`, you still need to duplicate the same amount of code. I don't how this will improve anything :)