# Passing class type in to a filter function

Tags: java

I am trying to return a filtered list of `rooms` by the room Class (SurgeryRoom or TechRoom).  Is there a way to do it by passing the room Class in as an argument to `getAvailableRooms()` instead of having the two private methods?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoomBooker {

    private List<IRoom> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    public RoomBooker() {
        // Demo data
        rooms.add(new SurgeryRoom("Surgery 1"));
        rooms.add(new SurgeryRoom("Surgery 2"));
        rooms.add(new TechRoom("TechRoom 1"));
        rooms.add(new TechRoom("TechRoom 2"));
    }

    private List<IRoom> filterBySurgeryRoom() {
        List<IRoom> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IRoom room : rooms) {
            if (room instanceof SurgeryRoom) {
                r.add(room);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    private List<IRoom> filterByTechRoom() {
        List<IRoom> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IRoom room : rooms) {
            if (room instanceof TechRoom) {
                r.add(room);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public List<IRoom> getAvailableRooms(String roomType, Date date) {  
        List<IRoom> available = new ArrayList<>();

        switch (roomType.toUpperCase()) {
            case "SURGERY":
                available = filterBySurgeryRoom();
                break;
            case "TECH":
                available = filterByTechRoom();
                break;
        }

        return available;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Guava by any chance?

Comment: No just simple Java 9.0

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575376/why-use-enums-instead-of-constants if you want to improve your code

Comment: @alfasin not sure you need Enum here, just do it differently

Comment: @azro `enum` is preferred over String-constants. True that you can check the `instanceof` but wouldn't it be nice, in case you want to add a new Room "type" to simply update the enum instead of creating a new class?

Comment: @alfasin over string-cst sure but if you add a new subtype of IRoom you won't have to change nothing if you take a look at my one-line method ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the class as an argument and use the `isInstance` method documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)

```
private <T extends IRoom> List<T> filterRoomByType(Class<T> roomType) {
    List<T> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (IRoom room : rooms) {
        if (roomType.isInstance(room)) {
            r.add((T) room);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Change the signature to `List<IRoom> filterRoomByType(Class<? extends IRoom>`

Comment: It's still broken, because you're returning a `List<IRoom>`.

Comment: I changed my answer. You can go for shmosel's suggestion if you do not need the additional type information provided by using the generic response type

Comment: So how do I now pass in the Class to be filtered? I tried the following but it errored `List<IRoom> surgeryRooms = roomBooker.getAvailableRooms(SurgeryRoom);`

Comment: You can reference a class using its `.class` property. `List<SurgeryRoom> surgeryRooms = roomBooker.getAvailableRooms(SurgeryRoom.class);`

Comment: `roomType.cast(room)` is safer.

Comment: @shmosel what does that replace?

Comment: @Christian `(T) room`

Answer (score 2):

make the method accept a [**`Predicate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) parameter i.e:

```
private List<IRoom> filterRoomByType(Predicate<IRoom> predicate) {
        List<IRoom> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IRoom room : rooms) {
            if (predicate.test(room)) {
                r.add(room);
            }
        }
        return r;
}
```

so now whenever you call the method `filterRoomByType`, you can pass in a function which defines the criteria for the `if` condition.

```
filterRoomByType(e -> e instanceof SurgeryRoom);
```

or

```
filterRoomByType(e -> e instanceof TechRoom);
```

Comment: The method doesnt error but now when i do `List<IRoom> surgeryRooms = roomBooker.getAvailableRooms(SurgeryRoom, date);` it wont compile with `Expression expected` error..

Comment: @Christian Look at the sample calls at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java `Streams` to achieve this easily

```
public List<IRoom> getAvailableRooms(Class<? extends IRoom> roomType, Date date) {
    return rooms.stream().filter(roomType::isInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And call with :

```
List<IRoom> list = getAvailableRooms(SurgeryRoom.class, new Date(1234));
List<IRoom> list = getAvailableRooms(TechRoom.class, new Date(1234));
```

---

Later when you'll add the `date` filter you'd be able to use the same method just improve the `filter part`

Like getting all rooms for specific class AND those which date is after date in parameter :

```
public List<IRoom> getAvailableRooms(Class<? extends IRoom> roomType, Date date) {
    return rooms.stream()
            .filter(roomType::isInstance)         //== .filter(r->roomType.isInstance(r))
            .filter(r -> r.getDate().after(date))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```