# Is it okay to create constant variables just for the sake of readability?

Tags: java, coding-style

Imagine if I have this piece of code:

```
System.out.println("Is the product:\n"+
                    "1. National.\n"+
                    "2. International.");
int choice = input.nextInt(System.in);
if (choice == 1)
    (...)
else if (choice == 2)
    (...)
```

So is it okay to do the following?

```
final int NATIONAL = 1;
final int INTERNATIONAL = 2;
System.out.println("Is the product:\n"+
                        "1. National.\n"+
                        "2. International.");
int choice = input.nextInt(System.in);
if (choice == NATIONAL)
    (...)
else if (choice == INTERNATIONAL)
    (...)
```

I don't know, I just bought the Clean Code book by Uncle Bob and I started to question myself.

Comment: Why should it  be bad? In my opinion it depends on the context. In your example it is perfect. If you have something like a margin of 37 pixels it would confuse me.

Comment: Well, IDK if it consumes more memory or anything.

Comment: Yes, it is OK.  Indeed a lot of people recommend this as good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe constant is better than the `magic` number.
With constant, you control the definition in one place and better naming. It'll affect your further maintainability of the code.
And try using `enum` instead of constant in some situations. `Enum` has more pros than constant.
In this case enum example is similar to the below code:

```java
enum UserInput {
    NATIONAL(1), INTERNATIONAL(2), UNKNOWN(-1);

    private int input;

    public int getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    UserInput(int i) {
        this.input = i;
    }

    public static UserInput getUserInput(int input) {
        for (UserInput userInput: UserInput.values()) {
            if (userInput.getInput() == input) {
                return userInput;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Is the product:\n"+
                "1. National.\n"+
                "2. International.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (UserInput.getUserInput(choice)) {
            case NATIONAL: break;
            case INTERNATIONAL: break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

check is for more: [Why use Enums instead of Constants? Which is better in terms of software design and readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575376/why-use-enums-instead-of-constants-which-is-better-in-terms-of-software-design)

Comment: I decided to use constants because I don't really know how to work with enums if the user's input is present.

Comment: @SebastianArrieta, I update the code with an enum example, in this case. I hope it helps you learn `enum`. It is really useful in Java.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to Some variable(constants) or Code multiple, then you make constants for better readablity and understanding.
For Example -:
if (choice == NATIONAL)
    (...)
else if (choice == INTERNATIONAL)
    (...)

is right when you have to use INTERNATIONAL and NATIONAL multiple times