# Android: how to pass an activity as extra within an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, data-extraction

I need to launch an activity telling what activity it must launch after the user has completed a form.

I tried this and it seems correct

```
new Intent(this, Activity1.class)
     .putExtra("myActivity", Activity2.class);
```

If I had to make it launch another class I would do

```
new Intent(this, Activity1.class)
     .putExtra("myActivity", AnotherActivity.class);
```

Is it the right way?

In Activity1 how should I get the extra argument of .class type?

Comment: You don't do that; pass a unique value like a String "ActivityB" or C or integer like 1, 2, 3 then switch when you get the extras to know which activity to launch!

Comment: you're right , but it seemed like a way to avoid the switch part.

Comment: How many activities do you need to choose from? Maybe from there I can help

Comment: actually there are two activities

Comment: That should be easy; let me give an answer below for you to try;

Comment: another problem is that Activity1 is in a library so it doesn't see Activity2 or AnotherActivity, they are in the same module that calls the library

Comment: I don't think that is a problem; just wait a minute for me to finish this part

Comment: @user3290180 I think what you are doing is wrong, you can pass a class object using intent, not the class itself,   An intent is meant for passing objects/data between two components of an application or launch an activity please refer [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Why? if I could pass a class object then I could also use it as a variable to launch that activity with another intent

Answer (score 2):

Pass the Activity's name with the package, then get the desired class through reflection.

Passing the data:

```
new Intent(this, Activity1.class)
     .putExtra("myActivity", "com.mypackage.activity.Activity2");
```

Getting the desired activity:

```
String desiredActivityName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myActivity");
Class<? extends Activity> targetActivity = Class.forName(desiredActivityName).asSubclass(Activity.class);
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, targetActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample code:

```
private static final int LAUNCH_A = 100;
private static final int LAUNCH_B = 200;

//launch activity here with extras to decide which other activity to launch next

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);

//Now decide here, which activity you want to launch in the next one

if(shouldLaunchA){
   intent.putExtra("LAUNCH_TARGET", LAUNCH_A); 
}else{
   intent.putExtra("LAUNCH_TARGET", LAUNCH_B);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in your Activity 1, you can get the extras and switch on them:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

// you could place this as a class level variable:
int launchTarget = intent.getExtras().getInt("LAUNCH_TARGET");

switch(launchTarget){
   case 100:
      //Launch activity A
      break;
   case 200:
      //launch activity B
      break;
}
```

That is all you need to get this working!

Like I hinted above, you should set the `launchTarget` variable as a class level variable so you can access it once the user has enter data to your `EditText` fields and clicked a button to submit!

Good luck and let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: This is the correct answer, but doing it with enum might be cleaner. "class enum{OPEN_A,OPEN_B;}"

Comment: Enums can be very expensive though

Comment: @Eenvicible can you elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183904/should-i-strictly-avoid-using-enums-on-android check this out

Answer (score -1):

Why do you ant to launch an activity which inturn launches other activity. Instead, use if or switch conditions to lauch different activities directly

Create the following class

```js
public void startIntent(Class c){
startActivity(new Intent(youActivity.this,c)
}
```

If you want to use if statements to launch different activities

```js
if(your condition){
startIntent(Activity1.class)
}
if(another condition){
startIntent(anotherActivity.class)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could make a class where I set the class object I need to launch after Activity1 as completed the task, then this will get it from the same class