# Kotlin enum class in Android performance

Tags: android, performance, enums, kotlin

In Java we are told to [strictly avoid using enums on Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#Overhead) because they take up twice the memory.

Does this apply to `enum class` in Kotlin aswell? Will a Kotlin `enum` be compiled into a Java `enum`?

Comment: You might be also interested in whether you should really avoid enums on Android or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183904/should-i-strictly-avoid-using-enums-on-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143256/why-was-avoid-enums-where-you-only-need-ints-removed-from-androids-performanc

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would appear so, yes.

I created this in Kotlin:

```
enum class Thingies {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

And decompiled it with `javap -v`, and here is the header:

```
public final class Thingies extends java.lang.Enum<Thingies>
minor version: 0
major version: 52
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER, ACC_ENUM
```

Bottom line: they are identical, so you probably have to treat them the same way.

Comment: Now folks at Google say its okay to use enums, please check out  https://youtu.be/IrMw7MEgADk?t=857

Comment: If you Proguard the class, does it turn them into ints?

Comment: @Rambo7 - They say it's okay to use enums now but they also say string/int constants are still better.

Answer (score 6):

They are exactly the same thing, a Kotlin Enum *is* a Java JVM Enum.

Answer (score 5):

You can most definitely use enums in Android **now**, they specifically discussed this topic in this Google I/O video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMw7MEgADk
(if you don't want to watch the whole video, then start from 11:30 ish to 14:40).

Comment: That video he said that it still isn't as efficient as using an int. Android Framework devs still avoid them for this reason.

Comment: @phreakhead you don't have listened until the 14:40. https://youtu.be/IrMw7MEgADk?t=858

Comment: I would recommend watching from 10:15 instead if you have time for that extra minute to get the context: It was comparing dalvik and ART.

Comment: Yes agree, it's still maybe not as efficient as using int, but still for normal size project, using 10-50 enums will not have that huge impact on your performance and memory, so I would say use ONLY enums and be happy :)